# QueryDSL enums as result of case when causing ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

I am trying to build a query that returns just an enum value. I thought using a case when would be the right way to go, but I run into the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getFirstThenNode(CaseNode.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
```

This is the query causing the Exception (I tried to abstract it as far as possible to simplify the example (e.count is actually a subquery)):

```
QEntity e = new QEntity("e");

EnumExpression<EnumType> cases = new CaseBuilder()
    .when(e.count.eq(1)).then(EnumType.ONE)
    .when(e.count.eq(2)).then(EnumType.TWO)
    .otherwise(EnumType.MORE);

new JPAQuery(em()).from(e).where(e.enumType.eq(cases)).singleResult(e.enumType);
```

using QueryDSL 3.6.9

reproduced with QueryDSL 3.7.3

I am not sure if I am using QueryDSL the wrong way or if this is not supported.

Comment: Managed to do it via `.then(Expressions.enumPath(EnumType.class, "'" + EnumType.ONE + "'"))`